# TensorFlow Camera detection issue with its demo

Tags: ios, objective-c, tensorflow

When I change model in `TensorFlowCamera` demo, it failed to create graph.

Currently used code is : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/ios/camera

```
tensorflow::Status create_status = (*session)->Create(tensorflow_graph);
  if (!create_status.ok()) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "Could not create TensorFlow Graph: " << create_status;
    return create_status;
  }
```

Please give proper flow, how to change model in current available sample code.

Thanks!